# DataGrid: How to test if a column exists in a datagrid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I have a datagrid that I want to pass in a generic collection. On mouseover I want to test if the row has a specific column and return the value.

What I am trying to accomplish is to determine the type of objects in the grid based on the existence of a specific column. For example, if "SerialNo" exists I know the grid is currently holding a collection of Widgets. If "CustomerId" exists I know the grid is currently holding customers.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result?
Do you mean you want to pass in a collection of Objects, not a strongly typed collection?  Are you doing this with by binding to the ItemsSource property?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the row is of a certain type by casting the object and/or using type reflection on object the row is referencing.
What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure what type of information is going to be stored in the grid. I am hoping to keep the grid from knowing what type of information its holding.